# Battery connection

Tags: batteries

Hi I've put 2 batteries together on my skullcandy crushers so it has 2100mah but when i connect the 2 yellow wires to the circuit board it doesn't charge but when i disconnect one yellow wire it charges I've connected the 2 red wires together as well as 2 black wires together and only using 1 yellow wire will it charge both batteries together if only 1 yellow wire is connected to the circuit board ? As i say both the red wire and black wires are on the circuit board meaning 2x2 black wires and 2x2 red wires together and only 1 yellow wire connected to the circuit board will it still charge both batteries or will it only charge one battery iam thinking that it will charge both batteries even though theirs only 1 yellow wire connected to the circuit board please help me with this issue thanks

Comment: Could you please post a schematic of what you have wired up? It would be of great help in understanding your problem.

Comment: As i say I've connected the 2 red wires together and soldered it to the circuit board and I've connected the black wires together and soldered it to the circuit board and i only have one yellow wire connected to the circuit board the other yellow wire is not connected to the circuit board if both yellow wires are connected to the circuit board it doesn't show a charging light but if i disconnect one yellow wire from the circuit board it shows a charging light and i was wondering if it will charge both batteries even though theirs only 1 yellow wire connected to the circuit board ?

Comment: As i say I've connected both red wires to the circuit board and both black wires to the circuit board but if i connect both yellow wires to the circuit board it doesn't show a charging light but if i disconnect one yellow wire it shows a charging light will it still charge both batteries even though theirs only 1 yellow wire connected to the circuit board ?

Comment: Please draw it. And take a photo to find out if each battery has dual cells. The extra wire can either be for cell balancing if it is a dual cell, or it might just be temperature sensor. You can't obviously parallel the temp sensors, but then the circuitry can't know if the other battery is overheated while the other battery is fine. You have written the same thing four times now, and it's difficult to follow what you have done as there is no punctuation.

Comment: Iam not good at putting punctuation i don't even know what 1 is lol as I've tried explaining I've put 2 batteries together it has 3 wires from the battery x2 and when i connected the red wires together and soldered it to the circuit board and the black wires together and soldered it to the circuit board but when i try putting both yellow wires to the circuit board it doesn't show a charging light but if i disconnect one of the yellow wires it shows a charging light and i basically want to know that if i just leave one yellow wire connected to the circuit board and leave the other disconnected

Comment: Hi Crissy, I finally got it! You may delete your repeat comments. Many thanks.

Comment: Crissy, for punctuation just put a '.' at the end of each sentence. Then capaitalise the first letter of the next sentence. Clear communication is very important. We don't expect every post to be perfect, but posts with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get read and upvoted more frequently. (Proper capitalisation includes sentences, part numbers, brand names, SI unit symbols - V and A, etc.) This is site policy. [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages.

Answer (score 2):

The yellow wire is from an NTC thermistor, embedded in the battery pack, to monitor battery temperature while charging.

'NTC' stands for 'Negative Thermal Coefficient of resistance'. The resistance of an NTC thermistor would reduce with increase in temperature.

With both yellow wires connected, the thermistors would be in parallel and the lowered resistance would signal 'high temperature' to the charger and shut it down.

Soldering the wires on to the board (red together, black together and one yellow alone) would ensure that both batteries get charged (even though one yellow wire is not connected).

Temperature monitoring would be from one thermistor only, of course.

You would get more information at

[How to connect Li-ion batteries with thermistor pin in parallel?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/183244/how-to-connect-li-ion-batteries-with-thermistor-pin-in-parallel)

Comment: Thanks mate your a star as i keep saying it charges with 1 yellow wire connected to the circuit board but if i connect both of them it doesn't show a charging light but if i connect just 1 yellow wire it shows a charging light I've heard that if the yellow wire isn't connected to anything it won't charge the battery but i just wanted to know if i had both red wires connected to the circuit board as well as the black wires connected to the circuit board will the 1 yellow wire connected to the circuit board charge both batteries or do i need to connect both yellow wires together or separately